# Graphedit intelligent connect - weird behavior

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, video-capture, graphedit

I am building a graph using **ICaptureGraphBuilder2** in my directshow code.

I am adding instance of my camera and a **VMR9 renderer** to the graph and I try to **intelligent connect** it using **RenderStream** API using capture pin and format MEDIATYPE_video implemented.

If I use **ROT** to export the resultant graph built, I can see a **smarttee** filter, **decompressor** filter and a **color space converter** filter in between my source and render filters.

But in Graphedit, I build my own graph with the same source and render filters and try to intelligent connect it using **rightclick->renderpin** in my capture pin, no intermediates are getting added.

Why is this weird behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is behavior by design, [`IGraphBuilder::Render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390089) vs. [`ICaptureGraphBuilder2::RenderStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd311924). MSDN has the differences documented:

> **Smart Tee.** Some capture filters have a capture pin but no preview pin. To preview, the capture pin must be connected to the Smart Tee Filter. This filter splits the data into two streams, a capture stream and a preview stream. When you specify PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW or PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, the method inserts a Smart Tee filter if one is needed. Then it renders the specified stream on the Smart Tee filter. If you render a preview stream and the method uses a Smart Tee filter, it returns VFW_S_NOPREVIEWPIN.